# How do i specify which property will be used as default when binding with mvvmcross?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have my own Objects/Views that i want to bind to and i know that i can do the following.

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView,MyViewModel>();
set.Bind( MyOwnObject ).For( o => o.MyDefaultProperty ).To( o => o.PropertyOnViewModel);
set.Apply();
```

This all works great..

My question is how do i get rid of the For() bit.

When i bind to the built-in views like 'label' i don't have to use the For.

How do i set my own default properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of default properties is setup during the `BindingBuilder` step - which is called in `Setup` during `InitializeLastStep()`

The list is maintained by a singleton object which implements `IMvxBindingNameRegistry`

```
public interface IMvxBindingNameRegistry
{
    void AddOrOverwrite(Type type, string name);
    void AddOrOverwrite<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> nameExpression);
}
```

To add your own properties to this list, you can get hold of an reference to this implementation. Two easy ways to do this are:

In Setup you can override `FillBindingNames`:

```
    protected virtual void FillBindingNames(IMvxBindingNameRegistry registry)
    {
        base.FillBindingNames(registry);
        registry.AddOrOverwrite(typeof(MyControl), "MyDefaultProperty");
    }
```

or in any code (preferably running on the UI or setup threads) you can register with the IoC container as:

```
    Mvx.CallbackWhenRegistered<IMvxBindingNameRegistry>(registry => 
        {
            registry.AddOrOverwrite(typeof(MyControl), "MyDefaultProperty");
        });
```